# Does Clearing an ArrayList preserve its Capacity

Tags: java, arraylist, capacity

As the title mentions, if I create an ArrayList with initial capacity 500 and then clear it after some time will its *capacity* still be 500 ? or do I need to re-init it for that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it preserves its capacity. (at least, not in the implementation of the Oracle VM):

```
/**
 * Removes all of the elements from this list.  The list will
 * be empty after this call returns.
 */
public void clear() {
    modCount++;

    // Let gc do its work
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        elementData[i] = null;

    size = 0;
}
```

Just to be clear: an `ArrayList` is backed by an array (e.g. int[] for ArrayList) and that array is expanded whenever you go over capacity by creating a new array and copying things over. Clearing will not (as seen in the code) create a new smaller array, copy things there, and destroy the old big array.

Answer (score 3):

No, arrayList's capacity is not changed if you remove the elements from the list. But you can do that yourself using **[trimToSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize%28%29)**.

In general, you don't need to worry about the capacity as it's increased as you add more elements. The possible reason to worry about capacity is performance due to frequent re-allocation. Otherwise, you don't need to worry about re-initializing the capacity.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [Capacity of ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3564928/584420), I could find that the capacity is not reset. Find the sample code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ArrayList<Object> al = new ArrayList<Object>(500);
            System.out.println(getCapacity(al));
            for (int i = 0; i < 550; i++) {
                al.add(new Object());
            }
            System.out.println(getCapacity(al));
            al.clear();
            System.out.println(getCapacity(al));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static int getCapacity(ArrayList<?> l) throws Exception {
        Field dataField = ArrayList.class.getDeclaredField("elementData");
        dataField.setAccessible(true);
        return ((Object[]) dataField.get(l)).length;
    }
}
```