# remove() method of arraylist is leading to shrinking size of arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have read that when we remove an `Object` from `ArrayList`, its size doesn't decrease.

I tried the below code to test this, but found that size is decreased. Could anyone correct or explain this to me?

```
package collections;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayListExample {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    //Creating list of Books  
    List<Book> list=new ArrayList<Book>();  
    //Creating Books  
    Book b1=new Book(101,"Let us C","Yashwant Kanetkar","BPB",8);  
    Book b2=new Book(102,"Data Communications & Networking","Forouzan","Mc Graw Hill",4);  
    Book b3=new Book(103,"Operating System","Galvin","Wiley",6);  
    //Adding Books to list  
    list.clear();
    list.add(b1);  
    list.add(b2);  
    list.add(b3); 
    list.contains(b3);
    int size= list.size();
    System.out.println(size);
    list.remove(b3);
    int size1= list.size();
    System.out.println(size1);      
}  
}
```

Comment: ***I have read that when we remove an Object from Arraylist ,its size doesn't decrease...*** where did you read that?

Comment: Where did you read that?  Perhaps you read something about arrays and not ArrayLists?

Comment: Maybe the underlying storage won't decrease its size (which would be an implementation detail), but the `size` method will always reflect the actual number of elements contained in the list as stated in the javadocs.

Answer (score 8):

You probably read that the size of the *backing array* used by the ArrayList doesn't decrease, which is true.  If you put 100 elements in an ArrayList, it will have a backing array of at least 100 in size.  Even after  you `remove()` elements, the size of that array stays the same.  To free up that memory, the `trimToSize()` method is available:

```
public void trimToSize()
Trims the capacity of this ArrayList instance to be the list's current size. An application can use this operation to minimize the storage of an ArrayList instance.
```

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize()

Answer (score 0):

There are size and capacity.

1) Size - total amount of elements in list. It will decrease after remove element.

```
    list.add(b1);  
    list.add(b2);  
    list.add(b3); 
    System.out.println(list.size());//size is 3
    list.remove(b3);
    System.out.println(list.size());//size is 2 after remove
```

2) Capacity - total amount of "cells" for elements in list. It will not decrease after remove element.

```
List<Book> list1 = new ArrayList<>(3); //there is 3 "cells" for books
List<Book> list2 = new ArrayList<>(); //there is 10 "cells" for books(default value)
```

You still can do this:

```
List<Book> list1 = new ArrayList<>(3); // 3 "cells" for books
list.add(b1); //capacity = 3; size = 1; 
list.add(b2); //capacity = 3; size = 2; 
list.add(b3); //capacity = 3; size = 3; 
list.add(b4); //capacity = (3 * 3) / 2 + 1 = 5; size = 4;
```

You can add 4 elements in list with 3 "cells" because JVM will autoincrease capacity of list when there are not enough capacity( formula = (oldCapacity * 3) / 2 + 1 ).

[There](https://hsto.org/storage1/44742fc7/7d6f5cb5/d75ad62e/d5b70d56.png) is picture of next code:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("0");
list.add("1");
```

You can read more about capacity [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564837/capacity-of-arraylist).